# Alternatives for the template engine of AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, data-binding

I'm looking for a template engine like the one used by AngularJS, but I don't want to use AngularJS on my project so I've found two alternatives:

- RivetsJS: http://www.rivetsjs.com/
- Ractive: http://www.ractivejs.org/

I would like to know of more alternatives, I want a template solution like AngularJS that implements an easy two-way binding.

I appreciate your help (Sorry for my English).

Comment: Have you looked at `Ember.js`?

Comment: Ember.js uses handlebars as template engine and this is not a two-way binding. Thanks

Comment: ember moved to `htmlbars` which I think has real data binding

Comment: I don't think most people even really understand two-way binding, so I am going to ignore your comment wanting a two-way binding. Also, a templating engine usually just takes a template, and using variables you provide/javascript, converts it into HTML. There are plenty of resources that do this once, but it sounds like you want it to update reactively. So I suggest using [react.js](http://facebook.github.io/react/). It was written by facebook and is pretty awesome.

Answer (score 0):

You can look these:
- Backbone: http://backbonejs.org/
- EmberJS: http://emberjs.com/